# How can I use Sonar maven plugin to validate local code against Quality Gate?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have our project integrated with SonarQube remote server, with a **Quality Gate** configured.
Everytime we commit in master our gitlab executes that sonar:sonar and if the code doesnt meet the Quality Gate metrics , the build is rejected.

I would like to do the same in local before pushing to Gitlab.

If I execute **sonar:sonar** in local pointing to the remote SonarQube server it verifies the Quality Gate and persists the metrics in the server.

But, I would like to do the same without persisting the metrics as it's my own branch.
So, if I use **-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview** it doesnt persist metrics **but it doesnt check the metrics ( Quality Gate )**

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not possible to do such a thing yet, as Fabrice said.

I have a similar preview problem at work, so I just put up a **local instance** of a SonarQube Server in my computer, with all the rules/quality profiles/quality gates as my company.

That way, i can run as many **sonar:sonar** as i need, testing it locally before the commit, just by specifying the "Dsonar.host.url" parameter.

I don't know if that would solve your problem, but is definitely a way out.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, simply because the various conditions checked by a quality gate are usually the result of a complex and comprehensive processing that can be done only by the Compute Engine part of SonarQube.

This is why, currently, plugins like the [GitHub Pull Request](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/github.html) one only report issues that were found on the piece of code that was modified in the pull request.